# Box stacking problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I found this famous dp problem in many places, but I can not figure out how to solve.

> You are given a set of n types of
>   rectangular 3-D boxes, where the i^th
>   box  has height h(i), width w(i) and
>   depth d(i) (all real numbers). You
>   want to create  a stack of boxes which
>   is as tall as possible, but you can
>   only stack a box on top of another box
>   if the dimensions of the 2-D base of
>   the lower box are each strictly larger
>   than those of the 2-D base of the
>   higher box. Of course, you can rotate
>   a box so that any side functions as
>   its base. It is also allowable to use
>   multiple instances of the same type of
>   box.

This problem seems too complicated for me to figure out the steps. As it is 3D, I get three sequence of height, width and depth. But as it is possible to exchange 3 dimension the problem becomes more complicated for me. So please someone explain the steps to solve the problem when there is no swapping and then how to do it when swapping. I became tired about the problem. So please, please someone explain the solution easy way.

Comment: I assume that when you rotate them, they have to remain axis-aligned? i.e. you can't rotate then by 30 degrees or anything like that?

Comment: Rotating means it is possible to rotate by 90 degree.means one dimension to another.No,it is not for home work.i m trying to learn dynamic programing.this is  a common problem in dp.so t need to know it.plz some one explain with some recuurence relation.and why your approach is correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you can solve this using the dynamic programming **longest increasing subsequence** algorithm: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence

Accounting for the rotations is easy enough: for every tower all you have to check is what happens if you use its height as the length of the base and its width as the height and what happens if you use it in the natural way. For example:

```
=============
=           =
=           =
=           = L
=     H     =
=           =
=           =
=============   
      W
```

Becomes something like (yeah, I know it looks nothing like it should, just follow the notations):

```
==================
=                =
=                =  
=       W        = L
=                =
=                =
==================
        H
```

So for each block you actually have 3 blocks representing its possible rotations. Adjust your blocks array according to this, then sort by decreasing base area and just apply the DP LIS algorithm to the get the maximum height.

The adapted recurrence is: D[i] = maximum height we can obtain if the last tower must be i.

```
D[1] = h(1);
D[i] = h(i) + max(D[j] | j < i, we can put block i on top of block j)

Answer is the max element of D.
```

See a video explaning this here: http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/

Comment: here i get 3-sequence of height,width and length.so how will i find longest increasing sequence??is there sorting needed??plz dont feel bother to ans.

Comment: @Poita_: true, I updated my post. Thank you :).
@russell: I'm not sure sorting is needed, although it might help as an optimization. You can just try all possible rotations - I think some of them repeat, but you can just try all 3! = 6 permutations of (height, width, length) for a tower i when trying to put it on top of a tower j and see if a valid one works. If one of them works, great, if not, try another j. Don't hesitate to post back if you have more questions :).

Optimizations should be possible - there's no point of trying all 6 permutations, but it's the easiest for a first solution.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: not all permutations will be valid, you only try the valid ones of course. I'll let you figure out which ones aren't valid. Basically, saying "try all rotations" is the right way, saying "all valid permutations" is a bit misleading, sorry about that.

Comment: what if the 1st element has the smallest width and depth of them all? shouldn't it's height be added to some other tower, although no other block fits on top of it?

Comment: True, you must sort like you said and then apply the recurrence.

Comment: I don't think this algorithm is correct. Suppose there are just two blocks, 3x4x5 and 1x2x6. This algorithm finds D[1] = 5 and D[2] = 6. The correct answer is 9.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff - expand the set like this: `3x4x5(1) 4x3x5(1) 5x3x4(1) 1x2x6(2) 2x1x6(2) 6x1x2(2)`. Sort the set by decreasing base area => `3x4x5 4x3x5 5x3x4 1x2x5 2x1x6 6x1x2`. We have `D = {3, 4, 8, 1, 2, 10}`. The correct answer is 10 actually: rotate the first block such that its height is `4` and base is `3x5`, and the second such that its height is `6` and base is `1x2`. The algorithm gives the correct answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IVlad You're right that the answer is 10. Two things still bug me about this: 1) What you just did isn't the algorithm presented in your answer, which proposes a completely different way of dealing with box rotation. 2) In your worked example, if D3 is 8, I'm not sure why D6 wouldn't be 8+6=14. In other words, you end up producing towers with cloned boxes in them.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff 1) True, I used the algorithm from the video I linked to in the other question, I'll update this as well 2) You can assign an id to each box and thus avoid using cloned boxes. The solution vector in that case would be `D = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 11}`. Looks like I was sloppy the last time around, the correct answer is actually 11 :). Use the tower `5x3x4 + 6x1x2`.

Comment: I think if we don't allow duplicates to be used, then the complexity becomes `O(n^3)`, because we will need to check for situations such as when the tower is `(block with id 1) + (block with id 2) + (block with id 1)`. Meaning, whenever we try to place a block `i` on top of a block `j`, we need to check that the tower `j` represents has no block with the same id as `i`. But it should still work, at least I can't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: @IVlad Heh! Hilarious that the answer is actually 11 after all that. Surely we must have it right now! :)

Comment: OK, good update. I expect this O(n^3) algorithm can still be fooled (in the case that we want no duplicates), but I'll have to look for an example.

Comment: OK, here's the example. Consider the blocks {1x7x9, 6x3x5, 10x2x4}. By your algorithm, expand the set like this: `1x7x9(1) 9x1x7(1) 7x1x9(1) 6x3x5(2) 5x3x6(2) 3x5x6(2) 10x2x4(3) 4x2x10(3) 2x4x10(3)`. Sort the set by decreasing base area => `1x7x9(1) 2x4x10(3) 3x5x6(2) 4x2x10(3) 5x3x6(2) 6x3x5(2) 7x1x9(1) 10x2x4(3) 9x1x7(1)`. We have `D = {1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 8, 11, 16, 13}`. The maximum value is 16. But the answer is (at least) 1+6+10=17.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff - true, nice find. Looks like it doesn't work if we don't allow repetitions.

Comment: please take a look at my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534969/box-stacking-in-graph-theory/4534986#4534986 see if you think it is correct.

Comment: @IVlad: I know this is a very old post, but I have a very pertinent question. for the example being discussed, IVlad says the tallest tower has height 11. But why cant we use the following: 3*5*4, 5*4*3, 6*2*1 to get the height 14. I think IVlad has made a mistake? the towers above are in the form of (height, width, depth)

Comment: @Jason Orendorff : please read comment before this one of mine

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad I think at the time we were discussing it, the problem didn't yet allow multiple instances of the same type of box. You're right that with duplicates (as the problem reads now) 14 is attainable.

Comment: @Jason OrenDorff Sorry its an old question but in your example why is the D value for 6x3x5 is just 8. If you see 6x3x5 base is less than 3x5x6(who max height is 4). So shouldnt it be 6+4=10? Or let me know if I am wrong?

Comment: @tariq zafar I think at the time we were discussing it, the problem didn't yet allow multiple instances of the same type of box. So you could not put a 6x3x5 box on top of a 3x5x6 box. You're right that with duplicates (as the problem reads now) the result will be different. I think the algorithm is correct if duplicates are allowed.

Comment: @IVlad Why sort by base area? Sort by width or depth is good enough, right? Of course, sort by base area also works.

Answer (score 6):

The stack can be regarded as a sequence of x,y,z triplets (x,y being the 2D plane, and z the height), where x(i) > x(i+1) and y(i) > y(i+1). The goal is to maximize the sum of z picking the triplets from the set of available triplets - each triplet being one type of box in a particular orientation. It is pretty easy to see that enforcing the constraint x > y doesn't reduce the solution space. So each box generates 3 triplets, having each of w,h,d as the z coordinate.

If you regard the triplets as a directed acyclic graph where edges of length z exist between two triplets when the x,y constraints are satisfied between them, then the problem is of finding the longest path through that graph.

Comment: cool . what if one is allowed to use only one box of each type

Answer (score 3):

Let's first try to solve this problem in 2-D:

say you have rectangles with X's and Y's, and the question is similar (highest tower, but this time you only have to worry about one base dimension).
so first, you go over the whole collection, duplicating each rectangle by rotating it 90 degrees (swapping X and Y), except for squares (where X(1)=X(2) && Y(1)=Y(2)). this represents all possible variations.
then you sort them by their X side, from largest to smallest. in case of duplicate X value, you remove the one with the lower Y value.

same principle applied in the 3-D scenario, only now you DONT just multiply the collection's size by 6 (every possible variants of the W, H, D) but rather by 2. you do this by dismissing all variations where the width is lower than the depth ( so for each i, W(i)>=D(i)), and then dismissing the variation where the height is not the highest nor the lowest of the three dimensions (because the other two variations can go one on top of the other and this one can't join in). again, you also dismiss duplications (where W(1)=W(2) && H(1)=H(2) && D(1)=D(2)).
Then you should sort by width, only this time you don;t throw away variations with the same width (because one may fit in a tower that another may not) then you can use the LIS algorithm as described above by @IVlad :

```
D[1] = h(1);
D[i] = h(i) + max(D[j] | j <= i and we can put tower i on tower j) or simply h(i) if no such D[j] exists.
```

the trick was, you know that the width is the longest of the two, so you know the first element will not fit on top of any later element.

Comment: Can this be applied to the russian doll envelopes problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a tree (or some sort of tree structure) and parse it with depth search, calculating the max height from the individual vertical "height" (depening on rotation) values.

This (I think this is the basic approach).

Details over details:

The Tree root should be the floor, where any cube fits onto. From there you just create the child nodes of possible next (boxes that can be placed in a certain rotation ontop of the current box) boxes.
Recursivly do that for each box *and* rotation.

When the tree is build, go through it and calc the total tower heigth from *floor* to a leaf of the tree.

Comment: That's exponential (factorial even) in the number of boxes. He said he's specifically looking for a dp (dynamic programming) solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem consists of three steps.

1. Sort dimensions for each box so that comparing any two boxes reduces to comparing their corresponding dimensions.
2. Sort the sequence of boxes lexicographically so that for each box, the boxes to the left are the boxes that may fit.
3. Apply [the `O(n^2)` algorithm for the Longest Increasing Subsequence Problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence.c).

The third step is the most expensive and bumps the complexity of the solution to `O(n^2)`.
If you would like to read a complete explanation of the approach, how each step contributes to finding an answer, and full code, have a look at [the blog post I wrote about the problem](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/03/25/stacking-boxes.html).