# box stacking problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given are `n` boxes in three dimension (`h`, `w`, `d`). The goal is to stack them on top of each other to have a maximum height (boxes can be rotated). Each box that you put on top should have a smaller dimension (`w`, `d`) than the one below.

How can we do it with dynamic programming and greedy?

Comment: As this question stands it seems to be more about algorithms than C++ in general.

Comment: It's rather complex optimisation task. You'd better ask at  math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not sure what "smaller dimension(w, d)" means. Do you mean the surface area of the top side shall be smaller then the bottom side? Or do you mean that the sides could be arranged such that the bottom side completely covers the top side (is there a math term for that?). E.g 2x2 has more surface than than 3x1, still the former cannot cover all of the latter (afaics).

Comment: this seems like a homework question and kind of a hard one. But this is surely a form of a knapsack problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem

Comment: @madmik3: I don't think that this is the knapsack problem.

Comment: @madmik3: It's not knapsack problem at all. It looks more like block stacking problem, but I am not sure

Comment: i would consider it a knapsack like problem but let's not argue semantics. it surely something that you might want to consider dynamic programming for just like the many different knapsack problems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems

Answer (score 4):

This is the [box stacking problem](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/) - problem 4 there.

If you want to think about it yourself, think about how you can adapt the [longest increasing subsequence algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) for solving this.

Comment: Great video. But because of the way that algorithm requires you to clone all the boxes, if the input is just one 1x2x3 box, that algorithm finds a tower of height 4, using *2* boxes. I wonder if that's what mozhdeh intended.

Comment: @Jason Orendorff - even if it isn't what the OP wants, I think it's possible to prevent that from happening by accounting for the rotations when you try to place a box, not cloning the boxes. Or by cloning and assigning an ID to each box, making sure each is only used once.

Comment: i think that it is longest increasing subsequent problem.but i am not sure.

Comment: i do not know how to solve it in graph theory.and what is the best greedy for it

Comment: you know that we want to use dynamic programming so we can not check all the space provided and you that by rotation we have six state for each box so its not dynamic if we check all the space.

Comment: @IVlad I left a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem/2329685#2329685 explaining why I think that won't work. I don't yet see a better-than-exponential algorithm, despite all the high-voted answers...

Comment: @Jason Orendorff I'm pretty sure this is actually NP-hard.  If you take a graph with cycles you can split each vertex which is a cycle node into x "related" vertices and create the same type of a "DAG with a restriction" that we get in this problem.  So a cyclic graph where each node participates in at most 3 cycles is equivalent to this problem; I think >3 cycles also can be polynomially converted into our "DAG with restrictions".  Sorry, too much hand-waving, but you get the idea?