# 2D Box stacking no duplicates with height limit

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve a 2D variant of this problem: [Box stacking problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem)

The catch is that unlike the original, multiple instances of the same box are not allowed. You can still rotate the 2D rectangles, of course.

There is also a height limit imposed so the tower has to be less than or equal this limit.

The base of a box below another box has to be larger than or equal to (not strictly larger) it.

I've been trying to apply the LIS algorithm and the other restrictions seem to be handled, but I cannot think of how to account for the no duplicates rule.

So my main question is how do you account for the no duplicates rule if you are trying to maximise the height of the stack and keep it below the limit?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I realised that if you create the two possible rotations for each item like you do for the 3-D variant, this problem becomes very similar to the 0-1 knapsack problem. Since the optimal tower must be built using a subset of this sorted list **in order** then we have to choose which ones to take. However, I still don't know how to make sure no duplicates are taken. Any help on resolving this?
Thanks

**EDIT 2:**

I found this link: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/handouts/recitation11-19.pdf
which on page 4 describes how to solve the single-instance 3D maximum height version, however I think this will not work for the height limit version since it returns the maximum height for each call. Maybe this can be modified to accommodate the height limit?

Comment: Its not clear what the objective is. The most boxes below the limit in a single stack? The normal problem states that the objective is the tallest stack possible, but since we have a "limit" here, then the objective must be different.

Comment: Yes the objective is still the tallest stack below the height limit.

Comment: @TylerDurden, yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out the solution was just the 0-1 style except with a boolean table after realising that the order is not important since any set of 2D rectangles can be sorted into a tower which abides by the restrictions.

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail

Answer (score 0):

Any set of 2D rectangles cannot necessarily be sorted into a tower that abides by the height restriction.  Even if it could you would still need to decide which orientation to use for a particular box (rotating it so the base is largest, if it fits, would enable wider rectangles to be stacked on top but wouldn't be as tall.)

The non 0/1 version, where multiple instances of the rectangles are allowed, is solved via dynamic programming by creating two rectangles, rotated differently, sort the array of rectangles (enforcing a partial order, so that if rectangle i, with a specified rotation, can fit on top of rectangle j, with a specified rotation, then i must be less than j) and then calculate for i=0...n the maximum heights that can be achieved by a tower that ends with the ith box with a specified rotation.

The partial order is required.  In the 0/1 case, where multiple rectangles/boxes are not allowed, it seems that you have to generate sets of all possible rotations of all the rectangles/boxes, sort each one and calculate its maximum height, that doesn't violate any conditions, e.g. via dynamic programming, and then keep track of the tallest stack height possible over all the subsets (Note that there are an exponential number of possible subsets which, as in the dynamic programming solution for the traveling salesman problem, is much less than the factorial number of possible orderings of a set.) In particular, the solution http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/handouts/recitation11-19.pdf appears incorrect: if i < j but box i with orientation x can fit on top of box j with orientation y, then the tallest tower ending in box i with orientation x might contain box j with orientation y which wouldn't have been considered when H(i,R) was calculated, contradicting the formula.

Note that the strategy of creating duplicates also seems to fail in the 0/1 case because whether you can fit the jth box on top of the ith box depends not just on i but on whether there is a rotated version of the jth box underneath i in the stack.  So it seems you need to store the highest stack that doesn't contain any possible subset of boxes in which case we are back to calculating the highest stack for every subset of boxes.