# Box stacking without repetitions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, np

You are given a set of n types of rectangular 3-D boxes, where the i^th box has height h(i), width w(i) and depth d(i) (all real numbers). You want to create a stack of boxes which is as tall as possible, but you can only stack a box on top of another box if the dimensions of the 2-D base of the lower box are each strictly larger than those of the 2-D base of the higher box. Of course, you can rotate a box so that any side functions as its base. You are not allowed to use multiple  instance on a box.

This question has been asked on SO ([Box stacking problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem)) but with not "without repetitions" constraints. **How do we solve this using LIS.**

I have devised the following solution, can it be debated

```
H[j] = max(H[j],max(H[i]|i<j, D[j] < D[i] , W[j]<W[i]+ H[j] -H[j'] )
```

> where h[j'] is nothing but if the jth box is already used to in
>   computing H[i] . Since rotation is allowed , H[j] could be width or
>   depth of jth box

Comment: You probably need another dimension to specify the orientation of the box, in addition to the classic dimension of LIS.

Comment: Yes that's stored, else h[j'] wouldnt be available

Comment: Then what is your question? I think it is better to explain what you do in words, in addition to your formula, since it is easier for us to follow your thought.

Comment: I wanted a solution , preferably a LIS. I have already implemented in LIS, looks like it does not work in all cases. Though it passes all my test cases. Wil post my code shortly

Comment: Here is the code. Not adding the code on the problem statement as it may dilute the discussion. 
https://gist.github.com/devshop/d9df1479a04af560b19b

Answer (score 0):

This result was originally derived for the 2D case, but still applies for 3D boxes, as explained at the end.

It will be convenient if all boxes in an optimal tower are, or can be, aligned with their long dimension E-W.

Assume a set of boxes with an optimal tower that requires some (non-zero) number of boxes to be oriented both E-W and N-S. Rotate such a tower so that the bottom-most box is aligned E-W. Now consider the lowest box, i, which is aligned N-S. Clearly the long dimension of box i is less than the smallest dimension of its supporter box i-1; so the long dimension of box i is less than the long dimension of box i-1.

Likewise, as the short dimension of box i is less than the long dimension of box i, by transitivity we know that the short dimension of box i is less than the short dimension o box i-1. Therefore the entire sub-tower from box i up can be rotated 90 degrees to align box i E-W.

Repeating as we ascend the tower, it is clear that all boxes can be aligned E-W in any optimal tower.

Therefore each box has only these possible 'orientations' in an optimal tower:

- Oriented for **Height**: longest dimension vertical, 2nd longest oriented E-W;
- Oriented for **Length**: longest dimension E-W, second-longest dimension vertical;
- Oriented for **Width**:  longest dimension E-W, second-longest dimension oriented N-S;
- Absent.

Comment: I am talking about which face is used as base (there are 3 choices), so I would add a dimension to indicate which face of the box is used. I am not sure how your answer is related.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Oops! I am solving an easier case. TY.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DP solution in [the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem) and get rid of the "without repetitions" constraint by having a size n bitmap at each position.

This does sound like your planned solution, but I'm not quite following your formula or your code.

The index for each box is common between the 3 rotations of it and the bit in the bitmap for the index of the box is set to ensure the next rotations of the same box won't be processed.

```
for i = 1:n  
  Box b = inputi  
  (h3i  , w3i  , d3i  ) = getRotation1(b)  
  (h3i+1, w3i+1, d3i+1) = getRotation2(b)  
  (h3i+2, w3i+2, d3i+2) = getRotation3(b)  
  index3i = index3i+1 = index3i+2 = i

// sort the 4 fields simultaneously (hi, wi, di, indexi all belong to the same box)
// (easy to do in OOP by storing these 4 in the same object)
sortByAreaDesc(h, w, d, index)

H[0] = 0
bitmap0 = {false}

for j = 1:3n
  H[j] = maxi < j, wi > wj, di > dj { if (bitmapj[ indexi ]) 0 else H[i] } + hj  
  bitmapj = bitmapi from max
  bitmapj[ indexi from max ] = true

return maxj H[j]
```

Takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time and space.

Comment: Are you sure you want to start the loop for i=1:3n? Shouldn't it be for j?
Since a box has 3 combinations, and since the array is sorted based on area, while computing h[j], how are we ensuring that the box to which h[j] belongs is not already set in h[i]?

Comment: @NandishA Yes, just a typing mistake from my side. Edited to hopefully make why it works a bit clearer.

Comment: No I dont think this will solve the problem, it will get the result without repetitions but the height we get will not the best one!

Comment: @NandishA Please post a test case for which it does not work.

Comment: It does not work for cases where some previous stacks are ignored because they contain the current box, but they would give higher results if the current type of box within them would be rotated. Consider 2D case, 2 boxes (base, height): (4,1), (3,2), when trying to add the last orientation of the box (1, 4) you can not, because you have already have obtained a suboptimal solution (4,1)-(2,3).