# How to order a collection with PartialOrdering?

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, partial-ordering

I need to order a collection of envelopes. Each envelope is described with its height and width. Envelope1 is smaller than envelope2 if it can be inserted in envelope2. If envelope1 cannot be inserted in envelope2 and vice versa, then they couldn't be compared.

How can i order these envelopes in scala? I couldn't find any information about that on the internet.

Here is some code I have:

```
object EnvelopeOrdering extends PartialOrdering[(Int, Int)] {
  override def tryCompare(x: (Int, Int), y: (Int, Int)): Option[Int] = {
    if (x._1 < y._1 && x._2 < y._2) return Some(1)
    if (x._1 > y._1 && x._2 > y._2) return Some(-1)
    if (x._1 == y._1 && x._2 == y._2) return Some(0)
    None
  }

  override def lteq(x: (Int, Int), y: (Int, Int)): Boolean = x._1 < y._1 && x._2 < y._2
}
```

Comment: This is not a simple sorting problem. This question might be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55891/algorithm-to-sort-based-on-a-partial-order

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn, yeah. This could solve the question (i mean, I could impelement this algo easily), but my intention was that if in Scala exist PartialOrdering, so Scala should provide some standard way to do that.

Comment: Something like this https://gist.github.com/ThiporKong/4399695 should get you started. Of course you first have an O(N^2) step to get the index pairs, but you can always optimize later if it turns out to be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Box stacking problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329492/box-stacking-problem)

Comment: Why not just extend the partial order to a total order that doesn't contradict it? Unless you are requiring the sort to be stable (which is a significant requirement in the classic sorting problem) this achieves the results without needing a custom sort algorithm that is "partial ordering aware".

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please could you give an example?

Comment: Suppose there are four envelopes--small, tall, wide and big, so that small < tall < big and small < wide < big (where 'less than' is understood to mean fits in), but that tall and wide are incomparable. How would you order the envelopes? Both (small, tall, wide, big) and (small, wide, tall, big) are reasonable (they are topological sorts).

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure your `tryCompare` function is entirely correct. An envelope fits in another if it's both narrower and shorter. It won't fit if it's either taller *or* wider. That's assuming one isn't allowed to rotate the envelope (which would make things much more interesting).

Comment: @ColonelPanic, yes you're right, but given task have a requirement, that envelopes couldn't be rotated.

Comment: @ColonelPanic, this question is more about Scala and PartialOrdering, and less about exact algo. I solve this task by using DP approach

Answer (score 1):

What you are interested in is [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and there is a classical algorithm to perform it with complexity in the order of number of edges. In your case you will have an edge between two envelopes if and only if the first one is smaller(and the edge should point from the smaller to the bigger one).